# Estimation of standard deviation of the noise in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, inference, model

Lets **Y= f(X)+ ε** be our model , we assume that **f(X)**  is linear  with this form    **B0+B1X**  and  ε is a random variable  with mean=0 and std σ
i have read that the estimation of this standard deviation is RSE.

**RSE = (RSS/n-2)^1/2**

how do we came up with this estimation ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Hocine, welcome to cv! I think you mean RSE=(RSS/(n-2))^(1/2), so we divide by RSS by (n-2). If you stumbled about some text writing RSS/n  - 2, then it is just a typo.